# How would I reset a usb hub multiplier driver?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I have a usb port which connects a [little man usb hub](http://www.presentsformen.co.uk/product.asp?pf_id=8199&src=base) I got for Christmas. It worked fine to begin with however now it works on any computer other than my own. When I plug the man in it lights up and when I plug things into the man it says they have malfunctioned but when I plug them straight into tha port it's fine. Is there somesort of driver that needs to be refreshed? I have no idea how these work so please explain!

I use windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

A little more is needed it to explain better, so here it goes what I think it is a simple task for you who doesn't have any idea on "how these work".

Go to COMPUTER, (Right click it) Select PROPERTIES. Then somewhere there should be DEVICE MANAGER (somewhere because I don't know 7 OS very well) Open it. Expand the USB something, like USB GENERIC HUB, expand it and check if you have something like a yellow sign in front. If you have, just uninstall that thing, disconnect the Christmas Hub and restart your PC. Then reconnect the Christmas hub and Windows should automatically install it. If you can't see any yellow sign, you have to figure out which of those USB things is actually your hub, that depends on your PC, and if its named like CHRISTMAS HUB or just Generic USB Hub Device (This is just an example because I don't know what it says in your language.) If you could find which one is really your Christmas hub, uninstall it and do the PC restart thing.

What U am trying to explain to you is just cleaning the previous driver installed, for it to be like if your PC never had your HUB installed, and then reconnecting it like the first time. If this doesn't fix it, there can only be two other things. Put the Christmas Hub in trash because it's broken and ask for another, or ask for a more complicated Fix to some one more expert than me cause you have a bigger problem. But I really hope my help is enough, better for you because of your hub and better for me because I will sleep better.

PS: When you uninstall the HUB from the Device Manager, reboot the system, reconnect the HUB and WAIT for Windows or whatever your OS is to automatically install your hub. Don't go mad connecting other stuff in your HUB, just wait till your system says it's OK.
Hope your hub is plug and play. Should be.

PS2: If this doesn't help, please for your concern, put more info about your system and machine, it can help someone who wants to help you. Like, how many ports of USB do you have on your machine, and which ones are you using and with what. It maybe seems like a stupid question but if you're pushing too much energy from others USB ports can cause faulty things on others USB devices. CPU based on Windows 7 like yours should have a good power supply but we can't put the microwave and washing machine and TV and VCR all the same time.

Comment: I am very sorry to tell you this now but, as it may not seem from the question, I am not a complete computer novice and really you could have fit that few into a few sentances. I am very sorry that you spent that time writing this answer and I am very greatfull but this has not fixed the problem, I had already tried reinstalling the driver of the device but is there a way of reinstalling the driver of the actual splitter? The error doesn't occour until I insert a device into the splitter. I am powering a small usb flash drive.